# How to reset admin user access from database in X-Cart?

Tags: x-cart

I want to reset admin user access of X-Xart backend.
I have database access.
How can i do? 
Can you please help me?

Thank you.

Comment: x-cart is open source. So study its source code and read its documentation. Your question is a sysadmin question so is off-topic on StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

what X-Cart version do you have? There are two X-Carts: X-Cart 4 Classic and X-Cart 5 which have very different database structures.

UPDATE 03.09.2018
X-Cart 4 https://help.x-cart.com/index.php?title=X-Cart:FAQs#How_do_I_change_or_reset_my_admin_password.3F_.28I_lost_it.29

Comment: Hello Alex,
My X-cart  version is 4

Comment: See https://help.x-cart.com/index.php?title=X-Cart:FAQs#How_do_I_change_or_reset_my_admin_password.3F_.28I_lost_it.29

Comment: Other link https://help.x-cart.com/index.php?title=X-Cart:How_do_I_change_or_reset_my_admin_password%3F_%28I_lost_it%29