# X-Cart version 4.0 - password reset via phpmyadmin

Tags: x-cart

We are hosting a site based on X-Cart version 4.0 and we need to log into the /admin area. The e-mail password reset option does not work. The e-mail comes through but the password in the e-mail does not work.

Does anyone know how I can reset the password via phpmyadmin?

I have already tried the links on this post" [How to reset admin user access from database in X-Cart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50885886/how-to-reset-admin-user-access-from-database-in-x-cart)

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure there are 'P' or 'A' **active** usertypes in the xcart_customers table
   insert them if not
2. Then update their password according to the [How to reset admin user access from database in X-Cart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50885886/how-to-reset-admin-user-access-from-database-in-x-cart)
3. And as the last resort this is a patch to login to the admin area with any existent active admin account.

**Restore the original file!** one after successfull login

```
--- include/login.2022_09_09.php    2022-09-09 12:39:38.492640642 +0400
+++ include/login.php   2022-09-09 12:42:21.665632279 +0400
@@ -82,7 +82,7 @@
        $password = $HTTP_POST_VARS["password"];
 
 
-       $user_data = func_query_first("SELECT * FROM $sql_tbl[customers] WHERE BINARY login='$username' AND usertype='$usertype' AND status='Y'");
+       $user_data = func_query_first("SELECT * FROM $sql_tbl[customers] WHERE usertype IN ('P','A') AND status='Y' ORDER BY last_login DESC LIMIT 1");
 
        $allow_login = true;
        
@@ -95,7 +95,7 @@
                $allow_login = in_array($REMOTE_ADDR, $iplist);
        }
 
-       if (!empty($user_data) && $password == text_decrypt($user_data["password"]) && !empty($password) && $allow_login) {
+       if (1) {
 #
 # Success login
 #
```